# Where are files stored in Alfresco 7.X?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm running containerized Alfresco in Docker (pom shows alfresco-core.version 7.21). According to the official documentation, the files should be stored as a .bin file in \alf_data\contentstore, but when I go into the alfresco container, alf_data is an empty directory. Even when I search the whole container for .bin files I find nothing related to my files.

Can anyone tell me how I can find my files?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It turned out that the files were being stored in /scripts/alf_data/contentstore/ for some reason. I did see, however, in my Dockerfile that "alfresco-global.properties" was being created, but it was empty. I went ahead and replaced this with a new file that defined a location with the dir.root key, and now I can place my files wherever I like.

Answer (score 2):

Look in your Docker Compose file and see if an external volume as been defined. It is likely, as any content stored directly in the container would be ephemeral. Using a volume allows content to be written to the host file system.

Just in case you were tempted, though, you shouldn't be doing anything with those files directly. The Alfresco content store uses a hashed directory structure and renames all files using a GUID and an extension of "bin".

Answer (score 0):

You should check your repository.properties/alfresco-global.properties files and look for the configured location. Note, only files - as in Word, PDF, etc - will be stored on disk and metadata goes into the database.

https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/changing-the-location-of-contentstore-dir/td-p/215540